# Consecutive edits kick you out of the review process

Tags: bug, edits, review

When I successfully edit a post/question I am reviewing and then successfully edit it again instead of clicking `I'm done`, I'm kicked out of the review process.

Steps to repeat:

1. I enter the review process to review a First Post or a Late Answer.
2. I am presented with an item to review. The `I'm done` button appears, but is appropriately grayed out.
3. I click `edit` to edit the item I am reviewing.
4. I complete editing the item and submit the edit.
5. I am presented with the edited (pending) item to review.  The `I'm done` button appears and is appropriately not grayed out.
6. I notice a minor mistake in my prior edit, so I click `edit` to edit the item a second time.
7. I complete editing the item and submit the edit.
8. I am again presented with the edited (pending) item, **but I am no longer in the review process; there is no `I'm done` button.**  Instead, I'm viewing the question as part of a list of other questions.
9. To access the item as a review, I have to click `back` button on the browser twice to re-enter the review process, where can then view and click on the `I'm done` button to submit the item as reviewed, thereby registering a review credit to my account.

In my opinion:

1. The subsequent edit shouldn't have kicked me out of the review process.
2. I shouldn't have had to use the back button on the browser.
3. I don't believe the review to have timed out.
4. I believe this to be a bug.

Comment: I can confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for confirming.