# Converting an answer to an edit from admin/dashboard redirects you to the question page, after the answer has been converted

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

This issue is the same as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174834/converting-an-answer-to-a-comment-from-admin-dashboard-redirects-you-to-the-ques), except it relates to the Convert to Edit feature, rather than Convert to Comment.

Stealing Kiamlaluno's wording:

What I did was the following:

- Noticed a flag about an answer pending on admin/dashboard
- Expanded the answer using the arrow shown to the left of the shown posts to read the question
- Clicked on the "mod" link to convert the answer to an edit for the question

Once I did this, I was not anymore on the flag page moderators see; I was in the question page containing the answer I converted to an edit.

Also, just like the other issue, when using the button on the mod tab, this behavior does not occur; only when expanding the answer and using the 'mod' link that duplicates the one from the post itself.

The screenshots for reproduction look just like the ones I posted in [this concurring post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174983/152134) I made, except the obvious differences between the two conversion types.

Comment: This is *so* frustrating.

Comment: This sounds similar to [Consecutive edits kick you out of the review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169542/consecutive-edits-kick-you-out-of-the-review-process)