# Leave Convert to Edit button enabled all the time in the moderator flag list

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

In the moderator flags list, there is a "Convert to Edit" button on answers which are posted by the person who posted the question. This button is disabled at times, and I am not sure that the algorithm used is useful.

My proposal is that the Convert to Edit button in the flag list should always be enabled, as it seems fairly frequent that it's disabled when it would be useful.

#### Justification

When the button is disabled, it is required that we pop open the answer view in the flag list, and use the regular Mod menu and choose convert to edit there. When we do that, however, we experience this issue: [Converting an answer to an edit from admin/dashboard redirects you to the question page, after the answer has been converted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184334/converting-an-answer-to-an-edit-from-admin-dashboard-redirects-you-to-the-questi) (that should also be fixed, by the way!)

Here are two items currently in the queue:

> [image: Answers posted by question asker]

Note that one has the button enabled, while the other does not. <strike>The only differences I can see in those two answers is the age and the number of answers. Neither question has an accepted answer, but the one with the button disabled only has that single answer. I've only just now noticed that difference with these two posts, so I'm not 100% sure if that's the determining factor.</strike> **<sub>1</sub>**

It is perhaps coincidental, but these buttons being (dis)abled are reverse of the action needing to be taken. The one with the disabled button needed to be converted to an edit; the one with the enabled button was an attempt to answer their own question.

<strike>If I'm right about the determining factor here (that the answer is the only one), I'm not sure that's useful. A good bit of the time, an asker will post an answer due to people requesting additional information. In such cases, it seems like it will be likely there are no other answers.</strike> **<sub>1</sub>**

---

**Note 1:** I was looking to create a userscript to enable these buttons, and I found something that I think is related as to the reason. It looks like the ones which are disabled are on answers which have comments on them. I noticed the `title` attribute of those buttons says, *"There are comments on the post. Please review"*.

That does seem to make some sense in theory. However, it still seems like I am often converting them, anyway. With the above-linked, separate issue regarding how the 'mod' link on the expanded view works, this is still a bit of an impediment to our workflow. It occurred to me to check if the button was reenabled once you expanded the view, but it does not. Maybe that's an alternate solution.

My plan for my userscript is to enable the button, but change the text color (and leave the title attribute), to point out that there are comments.

---

Comment: I can't help but notice that 'Dismiss.' seems a little out of place - why is it capitalized and with a period?

Comment: @Undo It's from a userscript, actually. I'd fix that, but I'm not that OCD ;)

Comment: @yoda Actually, the answer in the first item was posted by the same account as the user who posted the question; both by [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2623706/user2623706). For posts that don't have the same poster in question/answer, the convert to edit button doesn't even show up at all. [Here's the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672450/hartl-chapter-5-issue)

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know that was the case.