# How are flags assigned to moderators for review?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

I am not a moderator but very eagerly want to know, how are flags assigned to moderators for review? Are particular flags assigned to particular moderators related to their community (and if so, what if they aren't available)? Or is a flag shown as a notification to all moderators related to that community?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is something called "Moderator flags queue", where all flags are going.

Screenshot: ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203565/leave-convert-to-edit-button-enabled-all-the-time-in-the-moderator-flag-list))

> [image]

Each diamond moderator can access this queue, where he get list of the flagged posts and can act on any of these at his own time and decision.

No particular flag is assigned to particular moderator, on the contrary: any moderator can see any flag, including his own. (and in theory can handle it, but obviously shouldn't)

As for notifications, any diamond mod see a number in the top bar which is the number of flags in the queue, and it's a link to this queue. When new flag arrives, the number goes up.

Answer (score 4):

Flags are visible to anyone who can manage them in a queue or list (what manage means depends on the specific flag; non mods vote on an action rather than making a binding action)

- Recommend Close flags (such as "too broad") are visible to 3k+ users, via the close queue
- Recomend Delete flags (such as "not an answer" flags) to 10k or 20k users. (But largely dealt with by 20k users)
- Mod only flags (e.g. "offensive" flags and "other flags") are visible to all mods on the site

This means that flags are available to as large a pool to manage as possible; specific mods or high rep users are not targeted for specific flags.

Comment: Not accurate. 10k users can't see delete flags and there is no "delete queue", all we see is per-post amount of pending delete votes. Actually, there's no such thing as a "delete flag".

Comment: Also, in the close queue we can't distinguish flags from actual close votes, can't see who flagged/voted and can't really decline any flags. (so "manage" them is highly misleading)

Comment: @Shadow that's what I meant by "dealt with by 20k users". 10k users can see these things in the 10k list but can only reflag or dispute

Comment: I understand, but others with less knowledge will have hard time understanding, especially with wrong term (delete flag, such thing does not exist). There is some point in what you say, but as it currently written I fear it's more misleading/confusing than helpful.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was under the impression that was a name for a class of flag; "recomend closure" and "recommend deletion" (very low quality or Not an answer). I accept it's too general at the moment amd have put some specifics in